# Diode characteristic measurement - initial tester settings

Tags: power-supply

[image: Circuit diagram]

While doing the diode characteristics experiment I was instructed to keep the voltage at zero and current at max before starting the power supply. Can I know the reason why?

Comment: Perhaps whomever instructed you to do so would be able to say why?

Comment: actually he told to search for it otherwise he will tell me in the next class

Comment: Can you share the circuit diagram related to the experiment? We can't read your mind, so we don't know what experiment you were doing.

Comment: actually it's mere diode characteristics experiment. I don't think there is anything to do with the circuit diagram. However I have provided the image. you can go through that

Comment: @Rahul, the resistor in the circuit, which you didn't mention before, is crucial to understanding why the power supply current limit can be turned up. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about using a bench power supply.

Under normal experimental conditions you apply a voltage gradually while monitoring the current meter to determine if there is something off with your circuit that causes it to draw too much current. Since you really do not want to fry your circuit, you normally back off the voltage when you see this and try and figure out and fix whatever is sucking all the power. As such you want to power on with the voltage at zero.

Bench power supplies are also current limited. That is, when the current reaches the set limit, the output voltage will fold back, or stop rising as you crank the voltage knob.  Initially you do not want that feature enabled, or you want it set to a tolerable high level, or you will not be able to apply much voltage without the supply reaching whatever current limit you have dialed in.

Typically, once you are satisfied that your circuit is behaving appropriately, it is normal to back off the current limiter to some point above the normal operating current so as to provide you with some protection while you work on your board or experiment.

Answer (score 2):

Your instructor is having you maximize the current limit because there is a resistor in series with the diode, which limits the diode current, even if the supply voltage is turned up to its maximum (assuming the professor has checked that the maximum for the supplies he provided are appropriate).

If the current limit were turned lower, some students would invariably end up reaching the current limit without noticing, which would lead to invalid experimental results. By choosing a power supply with a reasonable voltage limit and an appropriate current-limiting resistor in the circuit, the professor avoids confusing students with these details.

> Can you tell me how the current limiter actually work? Is it just by adding some resistance?

Assuming you're using the circuit on the left, 1N4001 is rated for 1 A. And the maximum applied voltage is 10 V. Then the maximum current that will flow through the diode is approximately

$$\frac{10\ {\rm V} - 0.7\ {\rm V}}{100\ \Omega} = 9.3\ {\rm mA}$$

which is well less than 1 A.

Comment: Can you tell me how the current limiter actually work? Is it just by adding some resistance?